# Using Python in a Linux Terminal

Tags: python, redirect, terminal, piping

Okay, so, I just have a quick question regarding python and linux.

I have a program that collects and outputs data to stdout indefinitely. I need to parse this data, and I have a python program I wrote that will do just that. However, I cannot save this data to a file first, as it produces far too much output to save to disk. Is there any way to use redirects to somehow pipe this output into the program?

Example:

```
python parser.py < ./dataCollector.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but you want an actual pipe not a shell redirect:

```
./dataCollector.sh | python parser.py
```

Comment: Yep! That worked, mostly. I figured it would be that actual pipe, but I always forget that the input program goes first.

However, my script basically sets up another program, and that program's output is what I need. It seems when I parse this input, it is just the logging info from the script.

Comment: Oops. It did actually work, I was just breaking my loop on a newline... *facepalm* Thanks for the help!